# Vue2 event bus working after second call

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, event-handling, vuejs2

I have a nested component, and the child component should receive a parameter from the main instance, but the problem is that I have to call the event twice the get the parameter.

index.html

```
<div id="app">
    <button @click="displayComponent">Display</button><br/><hr/>
    {{ message }}

    <mycomponent v-if="showComponent" @hide="hideComponents"></mycomponent>
</div>
```

code.js

```
window.bus = new Vue();

Vue.component('mycomponent', {
    template: `
        <div>
            <h3>Im the parent component</h3>
            <childcomponent></childcomponent>
            <button @click="$emit('hide')">Hide components</button>
        </div>
    `
});

Vue.component('childcomponent', {
    template:`
        <div>
            <h4>Im the child component</h4>
            <p>{{ data }}</p>
        </div>
    `,

    data() {
        return {
            text: 'Nothing loaded'
        };
    },

    methods: {
        test() {
            alert('hello');
        },

        getData(x) {
            this.text = x;
        }
    },

    created(){
        bus.$on('extraCall', data => {
            this.getData(data);
            this.test();
        });
    }
});

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    data: {
        message: 'hello world!',
        showComponent: false
    },

    methods: {
        displayComponent() {        
            bus.$emit('extraCall', 'this is some extra text');
            this.showComponent = true;
        },

        hideComponents() {
            this.showComponent=false;
        }
    }
});
```

The text value inside the child component element is set to a default value, after the Display button is clicked it fires `bus.$emit` with the `extraCall` event with some text as a parameter, this should update the text value, and it happens only after a second click to the Display button.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<mycomponent>` (and its child `<childcomponent>`) aren't instantiated at the time the Display button is clicked because of `v-if="showComponent"`.

First click:

1. `extraCall` is emitted on the bus, but there's no listeners for that event so it is ignored.
2. `<mycomponent>` is instantiated after setting `showComponent` to true.
3. `<mycomponent>` registers a listener for the `extraCall` event in its `created` hook.

Second click:

1. `extraCall` is emitted on the bus and `<mycomponent>` handles it.

You might think that the `bus.$emit()` and `this.showComponent = true` lines should be swapped so that `<mycomponent>` gets instantiated *before* the event is emitted, but this still will not work because Vue defers the creation of the component until the next microtask when the view is updated.

This might work:

```
displayComponent() {
  this.showComponent = true;

  // Wait for child component to be instantiated
  this.$nextTick(() => {  
    bus.$emit('extraCall', 'this is some extra text');
  });
}
```

If the above code works for you, I still don't really recommend it though. You shouldn't need to account for the creation of the child component before emitting the event (it couples your components together). You should share the data some other way, check other SO questions on best ways to share data across components.

Comment: ok, this does works, but as you say not optimal and there must be a better solution. But since it solves the main problem I'm voting this as a solution, if I find a better one will post it here. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, since you are really nice and cooperative, I would ask you this, a while ago I did something just like this and it worked, but now it didn't, the only difference I found is in the html file, the condition for displaying the component instead of v-if was v-show, and when I change it, just works... would be any collateral damanges by using this?... AFAIK v-show takes more to load but then just displays right and v-if creates the component every time it gets called.

Comment: `v-show` only toggles a style on the element. If `v-show` is false, the component is still created, it's just hidden because of the style (you can see it in dev tools). `v-if` will actually destroy/create the element. If you use `v-show` instead of `v-if` here, it'll work with your original code. To decide between `v-if` and `v-show` you need to consider (1) do you need the element created at all times? (2) would having the element hidden in the DOM affect any `:nth-child` CSS selectors? (3) keeping the element alive with `v-show` will use more memory, etc.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your time, now it's pretty clear to me.